# Unable to run react-native release build

Tags: react-native

I am trying to deploy my react-native app to android. I follow the steps on this page

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html.

When I try to run it, it tells me

> not such file or directory '.../assets/index.android.bundle'

or I get

> Task 'installReleaseDebug' not found in root project 'awezaEduApp'

Using Windows 10 and react-native 0.39.2

---

### OUTCOME

I ended up having to reformat my laptop for other reasons and when i repeated the signing process it worked. On account of my previous efforts, prior to reformatting, I would presume that Eldelshell's answer would have solved it.

**Note**: I think that running gradle tasks in Android Studio's terminal would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute `react-native run-android` at least once. Don't worry if it fails because you don't have the emulator running.

> or I get Task 'installReleaseDebug' not found in root project 'awezaEduApp'

You have to execute gradle inside the `android` folder.

Answer (score 1):

> Task 'installReleaseDebug' not found in root project 'awezaEduApp'

For RN 0.39.x, you have to run the following for release build:

```
react-native run-android --configuration=release
```